# is it correct and natural to say "my years of experience fall short"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

There is a job posting that requires 5 years of experience but I only got 3. I was writing to the recruiter and I wanted to say that despite the fact that my years of experience is not enough, I possess the skills that the role needs.

Is it correct to write something like:

> Although my years of experience fall short, I believe I have the skillsets that meet the requirements of this position.

Or it should be

> Although the number of my years of experience falls short, ...

Comment: Generally, we say to fall short of something.

Comment: This is not a question about whether your construction is correct, it's about whether it's idiomatic. Do people usually speak like that and, if so, in what circumstances? Do years fall short? I should avoid the metaphor. (My experience makes up in depth and range what it lacks in years.) But this is merely an opinion

Comment: @RonaldSole But it certainly is idiomatic - and plenty of everyday speech invloves idioms which are not strictly grammatical. And we frequently discuss them on this and its more senior site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than acknowledging a deficiency in years of experience, I would turn it into something positive. You can imply that you're a quick learner because you only needed three years to master the role, for example:

> After having worked in my current role for only three years, I have mastered the required skills and competencies, and I'm ready for a new challenge that expands upon what I've learned.

Answer (score 1):

We do not normally give writing advice, but I see nothing at all wrong with that. And I prefer the first - there is no need to include "the number of".

There are however a couple of grammatical mistakes in your question.

In the first sentence you need the present perfect - "...but I have only got three".

In the second sentence the word "is" should read "are".

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct. This is a matter of opinion, but you may want to reconsider using the idiom "fall short" in this context. The term broadly means to fail in some way, which may not be what you want to emphasize here. Look up "fall short" in an idiom dictionary and see if you agree.

Something like this might work: "With 3 years of experience in x, I have the skillset required for the position."